How to detect image blurriness in react native using opencv android
I am trying to detect if a static image taken by a user is blurred or not.
I could not find any react-native lib (please mention any if available) to help with this out of the box, so i decided to custom build my implementation using native java code.
However am not sure about the implementation as am not a native dev by default. I sometime find the variant being high say 500+, not sure if this accounts for bright backgrounds and other variables. Does this implementation seem okay, what can be done to improve it?
package com.reactlibrary;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfDouble;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class RNOpenCvLibraryModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

public RNOpenCvLibraryModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "RNOpenCvLibrary";
}

@ReactMethod
public void checkForBlurryImage(String imageAsBase64, Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
    try {
        // Remove data URL prefix if present
        if (imageAsBase64.startsWith("data:image")) {
            int commaIndex = imageAsBase64.indexOf(',');
            if (commaIndex != -1) {
                imageAsBase64 = imageAsBase64.substring(commaIndex + 1);
            } else {
                errorCallback.invoke("Invalid data URL format.");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Decode Base64 image
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageAsBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        if (image == null) {
            errorCallback.invoke("Failed to decode image from Base64 string.");
            return;
        }

        // Resize the image for consistency
        int newWidth = 500;
        int newHeight = (int) (image.getHeight() * ((double) newWidth / image.getWidth()));
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, false);

        // Convert Bitmap to Mat
        Mat matImage = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(image, matImage);

        // Determine the number of channels
        int channels = matImage.channels();

        // Convert to grayscale based on the number of channels
        Mat matImageGrey = new Mat();
        if (channels == 4) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(matImage, matImageGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        } else if (channels == 3) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(matImage, matImageGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        } else {
            errorCallback.invoke("Unsupported image format.");
            return;
        }

        // Apply Laplacian operator in double precision
        Mat laplacianImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Laplacian(matImageGrey, laplacianImage, CvType.CV_64F);

        // Convert to absolute values
        Core.absdiff(laplacianImage, new Scalar(0), laplacianImage);

        // Compute the variance of the Laplacian
        MatOfDouble mean = new MatOfDouble();
        MatOfDouble stddev = new MatOfDouble();
        Core.meanStdDev(laplacianImage, mean, stddev);

        double variance = stddev.get(0, 0)[0] * stddev.get(0, 0)[0];

        // Set a threshold for blurriness
        double threshold = 160.0; // Based on my tests

        boolean isBlurry = variance < threshold;

        // Release resources
        matImage.release();
        matImageGrey.release();
        laplacianImage.release();
        mean.release();
        stddev.release();

        // Pass both isBlurry and variance back to JavaScript
        successCallback.invoke(isBlurry, variance, channels);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}

an approach involving the laplacian seems sensible, upto a point. you should involve a laplacian pyramid to accurately assess coarser frequency components. other approaches consider the spectrum itself (FFT/DFT/...) -- "image blurriness" has been asked several times before. I'm sure there exist answers for this. "blurriness": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+blurriness+-remove and I'm sure you'll find even more with other terms (sharpness, ...)

Its to difficult to detect image sharpness or blurriness.

@BarzanHayati why would you say that?

@ChristophRackwitz I believe you intend to measure image edges using Gaussian or other methods. I can provide some sample images that demonstrate it's not feasible to determine which images are blurrier than others.

you should not use ChatGPT/generative AI to write posts and comments. -- I am reasonably sure you don't grasp what I'm suggesting. if you think you have counterexamples, go ahead and show them.

@BarzanHayati it's totally do-able, the above code actually works, and I found more resources on how I can improve it using the link shared above.
The only issue I found is the app size will grow significantly due to opencv size (I'm sure there might be a way to optimize this) but doing the processing on the server might be a better choice.
